# Vaadin 14 TreeGrid MultiSelection mode with hierarchical data

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I use TreeGrid to implement my filter with hierarchical data in multi-selection mode.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVzM.jpg)

As you can see on the image above, the checkbox are checked for all three items. I would like to modify the parent checkbox(in this case "Default") to have some sort of selection indicator. If all children are selected, the checkbox will use a check mark as the indicator. If children are partially selected(not all), the checkbox will have ("-") sign to indicate that part of the items under this parent are selected and empty checkbox for zero item selected under parent.

I was trying implement this feature on my own, but i couldn't find a way to access the checkbox. Any idea?

Comment: I think it will be difficult to do this using TreeGrid's own selection mechanism. Personally, I would attempt to do this by adding a custom component column (using grid.addComponentColumn()) that would render checkboxes. I would then use this column to reflect the custom selection logic you are aiming for.

Comment: To build on what Tarek suggested, I would link this recipe, which slightly different thing, but could help you ideate what kind of logic to use https://cookbook.vaadin.com/treegrid-subtree-highlight